# PowerDesigner fails to generate database from physical data model

Tags: sap-iq, powerdesigner

I am trying to use a Powerdesigner tool for a DDL script generation. There is a prepared Physical Data Model which describes a structure of a Data Warehouse (contains tables, views, domains, dbspaces ...) based on Sybase IQ. 
Detailed versioning: PowerDesigner 16.6 (SP6), Sybase IQ 12.4.3

This model has a lot of sub-packages in it and under these one can find actual physical diagram, which holds Tables, References, Views and View References.

[image: PowerDesigner window]

If I describe it on the above picture, there is a "FINANCIAL" Physical Data Model, it has sub-package "BANK_MAIN", this has another sub-package "BK_ACCT_KEY_MEAS" and under this an opened Physical Diagram with the name "BK_ACCT_KEY_MEAS". There can be seen several dimension tables and one fact table.

So I press CTRL + G (or menu Database / Generate Database) to proceed with generating DDL. I tried to restrict different settings (all objects, just tables and views and others) but none of them are showing desired result.

If I restrict to "tables and views" I can see this content:

```
    disconnect;

    drop database 'BASE_MODEL.db';

    /*==============================================================*/
    /* Database: BASE_MODEL                                         */
    /*==============================================================*/
    create database 'BASE_MODEL.db';

    start database BASE_MODEL;
    connect database BASE_MODEL;
```

There is basically missing a reference to any table or view. I am still reading through corresponding documentation, but I am not finding any relevant information that could guide me to the result.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I don't have experience with Sybase IQ, however, for Sql Server I noticed generation issues when I didn't assign an owner to the table. Also, each table has a Generate checkbox. Make sure it is checked.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention there are Database, Tablespace, Domain, User and Group already assigned for this model. If these generation issues are somehow similar, maybe I am after some missing attribute.

Comment: I just created a Sybase IQ 15.4 physical model quickly with one table with one field and it worked fine. The table was included in the script. I used the preview feature in the generator dialog.

Comment: With your answer you helped me to realize, I have to put a cursor on the right place in order to generate the full list. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked out :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right approach to generate a DDL for database is to open any physical model that is under main package ("FINANCIAL" in this case). Next step is hitting CTRL + G (or menu Database / Generate Database) and then properly setting up the environment to generate. As this model pack contains many various packages, there is a magic button "Include Sub-Objects" under Selection tab. Activating this button allows to select all objects that are mentioned in the whole model pack (in tabs "tables" and "views"). Below picture shows this description in a brief.

[image: Selection tab]
Below is part of valid and desired DDL output:

```
disconnect;

drop database 'BASE_MODEL.db';

/*==============================================================*/
/* Database: BASE_MODEL                                         */
/*==============================================================*/
create database 'BASE_MODEL.db';

start database BASE_MODEL;
connect database BASE_MODEL;

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: A_ACCT_DETAIL_SUMM                                    */
/*==============================================================*/
create table _O_W_N_E_R_.A_ACCT_DETAIL_SUMM (
   ACCOUNT_ID           SYB_ID          not null,
   ACCT_TXN_TYP_ID      SYB_ID          not null,
   ACCT_STATUS_ID       SYB_ID          not null,
   PRODUCT_ID           SYB_ID          not null,
   GEO_ID               SYB_ID          not null,
   MONTH_ID             SYB_ID          not null,
   DEMO_ID              SYB_ID,
   ISO_CRCY_ID          SYB_ID,
   REF_ISO_CRCY_ID      SYB_ID,
 ...
```